# ListBox hides BindingList item after SelectedItem edit

Tags: .net, vb.net, bindinglist

I have a `BindingList(of T)` which is the `DataSource` for a `ListBox`.  The underlying Type implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Adding or removing an Item works splendidly.  It will also immediately show changes to property for an item in the list **but not if that item is selected in the ListBox**.

When you try to change the SelectedItem (or an item in the list which happens to be the SelectedItem), it just disappears from the control after the change (the DataSource still has it).  I'm not sure why this is.  I am not replacing the item, just a property on it.  Sample Type:

```
Public Class Critter
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _name As String = ""
    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _name = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, 
                  New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Age As Integer

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0} (Age: {1})", Name, Age.ToString)
    End Function

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, 
        e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
End Class
```

The code uses `Critters As New BindingList(Of Critter)` which is the DataSource for a ListBox.  As I said, Adding and Removing work flawlessly.  Changing the `Name` fails when that item is selected.  Using `DisplayMember` rather than `ToString` doesnt seem to make a difference.  Code to Edit in a button click:

```
Dim thisCritter As Critter = Critters(lbCritters.SelectedIndex)
' neither way avoids the result:
'thisCritter = CType(lbCritters.SelectedValue, Critter)

' rename the item
thisCritter.Name = "New Name"
' SelectedItem immediately changes to Nothing in Debug
```

Even simpler is this:

```
Critters(1).Name = "foo"
```

It works fine **unless** that is the selected/highlighted item in the listbox. Since it seems related to SelectedItem, this works (it also works to invoke `RefreshItems` thru Reflection, but that ought not be needed):

```
thisCritter = CType(lbCritters.SelectedItems(0), Critter)
' clear selected items
lbCritters.SelectedItems.Clear()

thisCritter.Name = "New Name"

' reset selection
lbCritters.SelectedItem = thisCritter
```

So, why is this needed when editing the SelectedItem?  Is it a bug or did I do something wrong elsewhere?

Editing the SelectedItem seems like a fairly common Use Case but there doesnt seem to be anything about this.  Many questions here mention `BindingList` as the solution to a control not seeing changes to a List, nothing similar to this issue.